# clearInterval() does not seem to work as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a JavaScript/WebRTC walkie-talkie app and require a button to be held down to send audio. It works fine until I click the right mouse button whilst holding the left which causes the `setInterval` function to continue working and `clearInterval` unable to stop it via its ID. It just continues on forever. According to everything I have read, `clearInterval` should stop it, especially if the interval is set globally.

```
var intervalId;

$("#transmitbutton").on("mousedown touchstart", function () {
    intervalId = setInterval(function () {
        console.log("PTT pressed");
    }, 1000);
});

$("#transmitcontainer").on("mouseup touchend mouseleave", function () {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
});
```

I have tried the start and stop buttons and it has the same outcome. `clearInterval` is not working.

```
var intervalId;

$("#transmitstart").on("click", function () {
    intervalId = setInterval(function () {
        console.log("PTT pressed");
    }, 1000);
});

$("#transmitstop").on("click", function () {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
});
```

Comment: my guess is you are creating more than one interval. If the interval is running, do not create a new one.

Comment: Increase the the interval timeout and check, other options are to use AbortControllor with AbortSignal to signal the controller to abort the action

Comment: If you: `mousedown` in the element, move the mouse out, then `mouseup`. You create an interval without clearing it, and next time you `mousedown`, you overwrite `intervalId` so the original interval is no longer clearable. (This may or may not be what's causing your issue, but is a flaw in this approach that's worth considering)

Comment: clearInterval has been working *for 25+ years*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you happen to call your function that creates it more then one time you will have an interval that will not be cancelable since you will overwrite the interval id. So either you need to cancel it, or not make a new interval.

```js
var intervalId;

$("#transmitbutton").on('mousedown touchstart', function() {
  if (intervalId) return; // either exit out and not create a new one
  // if (intervalId) clearInterval(intervalId);  //or remove it here
  intervalId = setInterval(function(){
    console.log("PTT pressed");
  }, 1000);
});

$("#transmitcontainer").on('mouseup touchend mouseleave', function() {
  if (intervalId) clearInterval(intervalId);
  intervalId = null;
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much. This has helped me a lot. I can see now that intervalId was being created multiple times. I used your code

`if (intervalId) return;
  if (intervalId) clearInterval(intervalId);`

which solved the issue. Thank again.